# Python subprocess failing due to TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Tags: python, subprocess, typeerror, popen

I have a command where it should execute in the path which I have given as input in the subprocess. I'm getting the following error when tried to execute it.

```
command = "bazel run //ros/src/bag_to_yaml:bag_to_yaml -- "
command = command + " ".join(tracks_ids)

print(command)

path1 = "/home/terli.vaibhav/development/github.robot.car/cruise/cruise/develop"
p = subprocess.Popen(command, path1 ,bufsize=1, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

This is the error I'm getting TypeError: bufsize must be an integer.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 45, in <module>
    execute_subprocess(output_dir, segment, vai)
  File "example.py", line 31, in execute_subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, path1 ,shell = True,   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 629, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

Comment: the traceback doesn't seem to point to the same line as the line you wrote, also the traceback shows the arguments are wrong, please check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) on the correct arguments and their arrangement.

Answer (score 3):

When using `shell=True` you have to put the **whole** command line as the first argument. The second argument happens to be `bufsize`. So your code is passing `path1` as `bufsize` and you are getting that error. You probably want to do this instead:

```
cmdline = command + ' ' + path1
p = subprocess.Popen(cmdline,bufsize=1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

By the way:

- You are specifying `shell=True` for nothing, because your code doesn't use any shell feature. this opens your code to security vulnerabilities for nothing.
- Depending on what the subprocess does you can use `subprocess.check_output` instead of `Popen` to get the output from a subprocess.

So I'd rewrite your code as something like this:

```
path1 = "/home/terli.vaibhav/development"
cmdline = ['bazel', 'run', '//ros/src/bag_to_yaml:bag_to_yaml', '--'] + track_ids + [path1]
output = subprocess.check_output(cmdline)
```

Comment: Thank you it's working but the subprocess is failing by returning return code as 2. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: @vaibhav Error code `2` *usually* means that the syntax of the command line is wrong. I have no idea what `bazel` is but you probably want to look it's help (maybe check `bazel --help` in the command line) and see what is wrong with how you build the `cmdline` argument.

Comment: Here string with `bazel` is the command I run on the `path`. These both are stored in different variables but as you explained in your answer we are concatenating these both variables so it is throwing error. Is there any solution without performing this concatenation ?